# Fail-safe wrapper for spary-json parseJson func

Tags: scala, spray-json

I want to write fail-safe wrapper for spary-json `str.parseJson.convertTo[A]`.
It must have logic - "when I can't parse json as case class `A`, I try parse it as case class `Error`"

```
def parse(str:String) = 
   try {
     str.parseJson.convertTo[A]
   } catch {
     case e:Exception => str.parseJson.convertTo[Error]
   }
```

but also I want to make class `A` a parameter.

```
def parse[A<:Obj](str:String):Obj = {
  import JsonProtocols._
  try {
    str.parseJson.convertTo[A]
  } catch {
    case e:Exception => str.parseJson.convertTo[Error]
  }
}
```

using:

```
...
trait Obj

case class Error(error:String) extends Obj
case class DataA(a1:String, a2: Int) extends Obj
case class DataB(b1:String, b2: Boolean) extends Obj
object JsonProtocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val errorFormat = jsonFormat1(Error)
  implicit val dataAFormat = jsonFormat2(DataA)
  implicit val dataBFormat = jsonFormat2(DataB)
  ...
}

...
parse[DataA]("...json...") match {
  case obj: DataA => "..."
  case obj: Error => "..."
}
...
```

I get compiling error:

```
Error:(25, 30) Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for A
      str.parseJson.convertTo[A]

                         ^
```

How can I fix this error?
Can I do this by another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying things, looks like that you've:

- defined 3 case classes with appropriate JsonReaders
- defined a generic function, which type is **lower** bound to Obj.

The compiler tells you that it cannot find a JsonReader for *all possible* classes implementing trait `Obj`, because you have defined only specific JsonReaders for Error, DataA and DataB.

To solve the problem you can use `Either[T,Error]` type for deserialization like:

```
  sealed trait Obj
  case class Error(error:String) extends Obj
  case class DataA(a1:String, a2: Int) extends Obj
  case class DataB(b1:String, b2: Boolean) extends Obj

  val strA = """{"a1":"foo", "a2": 1}"""
  val strB = """{"b1":"bar", "b2": false}"""
  val srtE = """{"error": "oops"}"""

  object JsonProtocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val errorFormat = jsonFormat1(Error)
    implicit val dataAFormat = jsonFormat2(DataA)
    implicit val dataBFormat = jsonFormat2(DataB)
  }

  import JsonProtocols._
  val result:Obj = strA.parseJson.convertTo[Either[DataA,Error]] match {
    case Left(dataA) => dataA
    case Right(error) => error
  }
```